# WPF DataGridTextColumHeaderTemplate bind width to TextColumnWidth of "*"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` with `DataGridTextColum` of `width="*"` (multiple of them, so that they're all divided equally) and I'd like to set the width of this `DataGridTextColumn`'s `DataGridTextColumn.Header` to its parent width (`DataGridTextColumn`).

However the code doesn't work, reason is I'm not defining `RelativeSource` correct, so my question is, how do I define `Binding` to `Width` inside `HeaderTemplate` of `DataGridTextColumn` to bind to `DataGridTextColumn.ActualWidth`? Code below!

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Username}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserSort="False" x:Name="DataGridTextColumn">
   <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red" MouseLeftButtonDown="EventSetter_OnHandler" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=DataGridTextColumn},Path=ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <Label>Username</Label>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

If I change the binding source to ElementName, everything works fine as expected, but i'd like to use RelativeSource to reduce amount of naming that I have to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridColumn` is not a `FrameworkElement`, so it won't appear in the `VisualTree`. It is merely a information-holder entity. What actually gets rendered is a `DataGridColumnHeader` for every `Column`. So, your `HeaderTemplate` contents would be present in this `DataGridColumnHeader`. And this `DataGridColumnHeader` uses its `Column` property to maintain its association with `DataGridColumn`. So,

Change your `Width` of `StackPanel` to `Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader},Path=Column.ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` .